# adding "uses-permission" in manifest doesn't work

Tags: android

**SLOVED**

Sending the intent like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

In the `onActivityResult` method

```
imageUri = data.getData();
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(imageUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I have found that this is a common issue. I am getting a `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:`
error when trying to `userImg.setImageURI(tmp.photo);`
 in my code. I have tried many solutions found on SO but nothing. I also tried using glide but no luck there.
The uri is read into an object, which I store in memory on runtime, and I request it with `tmp.photo`. I checked with logging that the `Uri` is passed successfully into the `photo` attribute. What can I do?

these are into my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My code is very simple.

```
ImageView userImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userImg);
userImg.setImageURI(tmp.photo);
```

where`tmp.photo` is a Uri object.
This generates all of these

```
Unable to open content: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A156
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord
{74dbab7 13175:com.example.gus.uniman/u0a168} (pid=13175, uid=10168) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4199)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5478)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2239)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1517)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1131)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:984)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:704)
at android.widget.ImageView.getDrawableFromUri(ImageView.java:900)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:871)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:490)
at com.example.gus.uniman.PersonDetails.onCreate(PersonDetails.java:78)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-07 19:24:36.919 13175-13175/com.example.gus.uniman W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A156
06-07 19:24:37.030 13175-13207/com.example.gus.uniman D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x76706ab800 (ListView) with handle 0x768d4df4a0
```

Comment: which android version/api that happend? Nougat?

Comment: API 25, running on a Nexus 6P that has 7.1.2 with June patches.

Comment: you has to request runtime permissions

Comment: Are you requesting runtime user permissions?

Comment: No, I just found an article on how to do that, but my problem is, where I go to the app under settings/apps/myApp/permissions, I don't see anything. I understand that somehow I need to present the user with the "Do you want to grant this permission message", but shouldn't it be visible in the settings too? My issue is probably very noobish.

Comment: You cannot hold the `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` permission, so if your error is related to that, you need to provide a [mcve] (full Java stack trace and the code that generates it). For `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, [use runtime permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it).

Comment: I updated my question. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have rights to the content identified by the `Uri`:

- In your original component (e.g., the activity that got the `Uri` via `onActivityResult()` of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`), or
- In any components that you pass the `Uri` to, if you include `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` in the `Intent` used to start that component, **and**
- Only while your process is around

In your case, somewhere along the line, you violated those rules. Perhaps you passed the `Uri` to another component without `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, or perhaps you saved the `Uri` to disk and attempted to use it again later.

See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more about `Uri` access lifetime.

Comment: Oh I see. Since I need those data to be stored in a database, I thought it would be better to just save a link to them. What should I do instead?

Comment: @Dinos_12345: If you are getting the `Uri` via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or other facets of the Storage Access Framework, you can try `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on `ContentResolver` to have longer-term access to the content. However, bear in mind that the user might move or delete that content "behind your back". If you are getting the `Uri` by any other means, you will need to import the content into your app, copying it to some file that you control.

Comment: @Dinos_12345: The simplest way to think of these `Uri` values is that they are akin to URLs to a Web server/Web service, but ones that require an authenticated user session. While you could save the URL somewhere, you may not be able to use it tomorrow, as the user's session may have timed out.

Comment: I actually read the whole thing you linked me to, thank you for that. I am still learning, so this was very informative for a noob like me. :)